# Algorithm choose for: event based time series prediction

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a dataset which is a electronic bus charger station, data include: voltage current and power consumption. There is no time rule in the use of charging piles, but I want to predict the power consumption of charging piles. Traditional transformer is based on time series, and the data needs to have obvious time characteristics, but my data does not, so I would like to ask if there is any good algorithm that can handle such problems.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include some sample data? I would be most interested in the granularity of your data, because my assumption would be that there are indeed some time series dynamics at play, especially [tag:multiple-seasonalities]: hour-of-day and day-of-week.